# (Python&Gurobi)AttributeError: Index out of range for attribute 'VarName'

Tags: python, gurobi

I am a rookie of gurobi.
The following code is try to implement the sum() of tupledict.
However, it cannot give me the correct result.
The console tells me the code faced an AttributeError.
I just do not know how to address such error.

Here is the full content of the code.
I fulfill this code in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import gurobipy as gp

m = gp.Model("test_model")

t_list = gp.tuplelist([(1, 1), (1, 2),
                   (2, 1), (2, 2)])

m_var = m.addVars(t_list, name="x")

print(m_var.select(1, '*'))
print(m_var.sum(1, '*'))
```

And the result is:

```
[<gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>, <gurobi.Var *Awaiting Model Update*>]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0aa273e3b4c3> in <module>
     10 
     11 print(m_var.select(1, '*'))
---> 12 print(m_var.sum(1, '*'))

src\gurobipy\linexpr.pxi in gurobipy.LinExpr.__repr__()

src\gurobipy\var.pxi in gurobipy.Var.getAttr()

src\gurobipy\attrutil.pxi in gurobipy.__getattr()

AttributeError: Index out of range for attribute 'VarName'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you found a case where automatic updates are not called. I'll mention something to the developers. In the meantime, add a call to Model.update() before you call tupledict.sum():

```
m.update()
print(m_var.sum(1, '*'))
```